# Add CRLF to a string of a CSV file

Tags: php, csv, utf-8, newline

I'm adding some values to a CSV file with data coming from a query, I need that these data were coded as UTF-8 with CRLF at the end of the line.
I tried several examples I found here, but no ones works for me, except to leave the file coded in ANSI mode and then convert it in UTF-8 using Notepad++

Here it is the code I used to write the CSV file and a picture of the result.

```
function letsquery($database, $query)
{
  $isOK = true;
  $query2 = mysqli_query($database, $query);

  if ($query2->num_rows > 0)
  {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2))
    {
      $array1 = $row;
    }
  } else {
    $isOK = false;
  }
  if ($isOK)
  {
    $array1 = arrayInsert($array1, 1, ['', '', '', '', '', '', '']);    //add some empty values needed by the CSV

    if (count($array1)<9) 
      array_push($array1, "");
      global $fnew;  
      $eol="\r\n";

      if (strlen(trim(implode("", $array1)))>0) 
        fputcsv($fnew, $array1, ';', '\r\n');
        \\ fputcsv($fnew, $array1, ';', $eol); tried also in this way...not working
      } else {
        header("location: tryagain.php");  
      }
    }
```

Notepad++ result:

[image]

Comment: To generate csv file, I always use the constant PHP_EOL. And, in my case, it's work fine. I don't know if it's the best solution.

Comment: `fputcsv($fnew, $array1, ';', "\r\n");` <-- you must put it into double quotes! Single quotes do not interpolate.

Comment: @MarkusZeller tried, but it's not working :(

Comment: @svgta any hint where to insert it? do you mean: fputcsv($fnew, $array1, ';', PHP_EOL);

Comment: Yes and not. Look at the format of fputcsv : fputcsv(
    resource $stream,
    array $fields,
    string $separator = ",",
    string $enclosure = "\"",
    string $escape = "\\",
    string $eol = "\n"
): int|false => you have to specify enclosure and escape before the eol

Comment: @svgta thanks for your reply, tried but not working :( at first attempt, passing all the six parameters, this way: fputcsv($fnew, $array1, ';', chr(9),"",PHP_EOL); 
I got an error message "fputcsv() expects at most 5 parameters, 6 given" 
I changed the code as: fputcsv($fnew, $array1, ';', chr(9),PHP_EOL);, but it's still not working, I have only LF and not CRLF, that is what I need.

Comment: Something else is wrong. Looking at your screenshot you have CRLF and LF mixed.

Comment: @MarkusZeller yes, the values with CRLF comes from the original file, I just have to add ssome new lines to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests I think I found a solution:

```html
function letsquery($database, $query)
        {
            $isOK = true;
                $query2 = mysqli_query($database, $query);
                if ($query2->num_rows > 0) {
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
                      $array1 = $row;
                  }
                } else {
                  $isOK = false;
                }
            if ($isOK){
                $array1 = arrayInsert($array1, 1, ['', '', '', '', '', '', '']);    //add six empty spaces
                if (count($array1)<9) 
                    array_push($array1, "");
                global $fnew; 
                $eol="\r\n";
                if (strlen(trim(implode("", $array1)))>0) 
                  fputcsv($fnew, $array1, ';');
                  fseek($fnew, -1, SEEK_CUR);
                  fwrite($fnew, $eol); // write out a CR/LF
            } else {
              header("location: tryagain.php");  
            }
        }
```

I did some test and it works correctly!